# make.service fails when deploying Go project file to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

### overflowers,

I've been struggling for hours on end trying to publish a Go application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Have followed helpful tutorials online for what I first thought was dead simple.

*[One of the tutorials i followed](https://blog.memcachier.com/2018/07/30/gin-elastic-beanstalk-and-memcache/#deploying-with-elastic-beanstalk) 

[Another one of the tutorials i followed](https://github.com/sudo-suhas/go-beanstalk-gin)*

*[An examples which actually compiles on AWS for me](https://github.com/mrichman/elastic-beanstalk-go-demo)*

My project structure is now:

The following files are all in my root folder:

```
application.go
build.sh
Buildfile
Procfile
```

### application.go

```
package main

import (    
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/user/:name", func(c *gin.Context) {
        name := c.Param("name")
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello %s", name)
    })
    router.Run(":5000")
}
```

### build.sh

```
go get "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"    //Have tried without quotation marks

go build application.go
```

### Buildfile

```
make: ./build.sh
```

### Procfile

```
web: bin/application
```

I have also read the documentation on AWS [website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html). And from what I can tell- my code, and the code in the demos referred to above, is correct.

I compress the enire contents of my root folder to a .zip file and upload to AWS through the web portal.
It fails...and in the error logs i can read:

```
2020/08/28 23:17:38.902079 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2020/08/28 23:17:38.902095 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2020/08/28 23:17:38.902100 [INFO] Executing instruction: Golang Specific Build Application
2020/08/28 23:17:38.902104 [INFO] checking Buildfile...
2020/08/28 23:17:38.902110 [INFO] building Golang application with Buildfile
2020/08/28 23:17:38.902148 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:38.908345 [WARN] Warning: process make is already registered...
Deregistering the process ...
2020/08/28 23:17:38.908368 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:38.913626 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:38.916919 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl disable make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:39.002192 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2020/08/28 23:17:39.086778 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2020/08/28 23:17:39.092606 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2020/08/28 23:17:39.166648 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2020/08/28 23:17:39.170861 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-enabled eb-app.target
2020/08/28 23:17:39.174735 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-app.target
2020/08/28 23:17:39.251327 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-app.target
2020/08/28 23:17:39.256334 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:39.338502 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:39.344691 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:39.348280 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start make.service
2020/08/28 23:17:39.358198 [ERROR] startProcess Failure: starting process "make" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start make.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 
2020/08/28 23:17:39.358222 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Golang Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: build application failed on command ./build.sh with error: startProcess Failure: starting process "make" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start make.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Unfortunately I don't have much experience of this kind of server configuration or any other deployment operations. So I do not understand "process make is already registered..."

...Perhaps someone more experienced in these areas might know what to make of this?

*Cheers!*

**NOTE**: The project has been able to compile and run on my computer all the time. It just fails when i try deploying it on the Elastic Beanstalk.

**EDIT**: Have now also tried deploying with the AWS Command Line Interface. In this case the logfile eb-activity tells me:

```
Executing: HOME=/tmp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/foreman start --procfile /tmp/d20200829-3130-13cz1sh/eb-buildtask-0 --root /var/app/staging --env /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/elasticbeanstalk.env
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/foreman-0.78.0/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `spawn': Permission denied - ./build.sh (Errno::EACCES)
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/foreman-0.78.0/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `block in run'
```

[image: AWS Management Console screenshot of my failed deploy]

Answer (score 2):

This may occur when the build.sh script lacks executable permissions. When that's the case "make.service" on beanstalk can't execute the script and an error is generated.

If you are developing on a unix machine try to ***chmod +x build.sh*** before deployment.

If you are developing on a windows machine you can't set the unix file attribute. But you can use this trick with Buildfile and deploy this way.

**Buildfile**

```
make: chmod +x build.sh; ./build.sh
```

This will make build.sh executable when the make service runs.

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered this issue when migrating the deployment of my Golang application to the Amazon Linux 2 platform from Amazon Linux 1 platform. I was experiencing a similar error in the build process:

```
    2021/07/10 16:33:21.411538 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Golang Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: build application failed on command ./build.sh with error: startProcess Failure: starting process "make" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start make.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After looking in to the systemctl status, as suggested in the error, I figured out the linux user "webapp" did not seem to have the correct permissions.

I added "webapp" to the sudoers file and now that build process finishes, and the deploy is able to succeed.

```
# User rules for webapp user
webapp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Where do you put that? What is the path to the file you are describing?